# Testing native application of Android and iOS

Tags: selenium2

I am searching for an open source automation tool for all mobile platforms ([Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS)).I have experience in using Selenium in all supported desktop browsers. I would like to know whether the automation of native application is supported by Selenium. If so, please provide useful links.

Answer (score 2):

Please check

- MonkeyTalk: open source functional testing platform for iOS and
  Android - [Link](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey/overview)
- Another interersting tool open sourced by twitter Clutch.IO - native A/B testing service for iOS and Android [link](https://github.com/clutchio)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium does function across both of those platforms using different drivers.  But only for browser functionality.

For Android, there is support for a native automation using a tool very similar to Selenium, called Robotium: [link](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)  They have some decent tutorials, example code and .apks and more there.  It does take more foresight during development and doesn't really sit "on top of the AUT" like Selenium can.

There is also the built in "Automation" tool within X-Code that will run code from Instruments directly against the device or emulator, but I have little experience with it to steer you toward or away from it. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW1)

Comment: Thanks Siva, I Have gone through Money Talk but while exploring I came to know that we can do Testing only if we have the source code of an app(android).But is there any tool where i can do functionality testing without the need of a source code.